# Debug local npm link package in meteor app

Tags: javascript, meteor, webpack, npm-link

I am writing a javascript library that is npm linked to my meteor app. I didn't yet publish the library to npm so it is only local.
Now my problem is, that I want to debug inside the library while using it in my meteor app.

I can debug the meteor app components and using a sourcemap and a standalone html test page also the library itself. But as soon as I use `import Library from 'library'` in meteor it minifies, uglifies and mangles it.

Is there a way to tell either meteor's build system or my browser to use the library's source map?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try removing the Meteor minifier package until you need it again:

```
meteor remove standard-minifier-js
```

Comment: Thanks. That solved it! Well actually I still had minification in my library but after disabling that it works perfect!